# Not able to find the file log generated for log4j in the file system

Tags: java, selenium, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have inserted below maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Used below log4j.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="C:/logs/demoApplication.log"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <priority value ="info"></priority>
    <appender-ref ref="console"></appender>
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"></appender>
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Inserted below statements for log generation:

private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(LoginTest.class);
log.info("Opened url");

Issue is i am not able to find the file log at this location:C:/logs/demoApplication.log
Can anyone guide me what am i missing here?

Comment: have you restarted the web server or the application server instance ?

Comment: it is wrt to selenium webdriver and is supposed to work on my system's file system.

Comment: what is the path of log4j.xml?

Comment: it is present in the root directory of the project.

Comment: for now, try removing the absolute path and mention only relative path. <param name="File" value="demoApplication.log"/>

Comment: Also, ensure log4j.xml is directly under src folder.

Comment: But how to locate the logs generated as i am not getting any error using the above mentioned configuration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215930/discussion-between-sara-and-user9261795).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration file you are using is for Log4J 1.x. You need to use a configuration that is valid for Log4J 2. It needs to be in a file named log4j2.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for notifying the log4j2 @rgoers.
When in renamed the configuration file as log4j2, it started working.

Comment: You might consider voting for the answer or accepting it if it solved your problem.